# Ceil and floor values in R

Tags: r

I have a data.table of integers with values between 1 and 60.

My question is about flooring or ceiling any number to the following values: 12 18 24 30 36 ... 60.

For example, let's say my data.table contains the number 13. I want R to "transform" this number into 12 and 18 as 13 lies in between those numbers. Moreover, if I have 18 I want R to keep it at 18.

If my data.table contains the value 50, I want R to convert that number into 48 and 54 and so on.

My goal is to get two different data.tables. One where the floored values are saved and one where the ceiled values are saved.

Any idea how one could do this in R?

EDIT: Numbers smaller than 12 should always be transformed to 12.

Example output:

If have the following data.table `data.table(c(1,28,29,41,53,53,17,41,41,53))`

I want the following two output data.tables: floored values `data.table(c(12,24,24,36,48,48,12,36,36,48))`

I want the following two output data.tables: ceiled values `data.table(c(12,30,30,42,54,54,18,42,42,54))`

Comment: how are numbers < 12 treated? it would be helpful if you posted expected output

Comment: can u make a clear example?

Comment: So you want to find the two multiples of 6 which bracket a given x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fairly direct way (edited to round up to 12 if any values are below):

```
df <- data.frame(nums = 10:20)
df$floors <- with(df,pmax(12,6*floor(nums/6)))
df$ceils <- with(df,pmax(12,6*ceiling(nums/6)))
```

Leading to:

```
> df
   nums floors ceils
1    10     12    12
2    11     12    12
3    12     12    12
4    13     12    18
5    14     12    18
6    15     12    18
7    16     12    18
8    17     12    18
9    18     18    18
10   19     18    24
11   20     18    24
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way we could do this, using `sapply` and the `which.min` functions. From your question, it's not immediately clear how values < 12 should be handled.

```
x <- 1:60
num_list <- seq(12, 60, 6)

floorr <- sapply(x, function(x){
 diff_vec <- x - num_list
 diff_vec <- ifelse(diff_vec < 0, Inf, diff_vec)
 num_list[which.min(diff_vec)]
})


ceill <- sapply(x, function(x){
  diff_vec <- num_list - x
  diff_vec <- ifelse(diff_vec < 0, Inf, diff_vec)
  num_list[which.min(diff_vec)]
})

tail(cbind(x, floorr, ceill))

       x floorr ceill
[55,] 55     54    60
[56,] 56     54    60
[57,] 57     54    60
[58,] 58     54    60
[59,] 59     54    60
[60,] 60     60    60
```